# Trying To Implement a Context Menu in Windows Explorer and Return Path

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

Ok, so I'm a little new to VB.Net and so I've struggled with this so maybe you more experienced programmers can help me out.  The goal of this project is as follows:

1. Create a context menu item that only appears when selecting file/files or folder/folders on a particular network drive in Windows Explorer
2. When the menu item is chosen I want it to pass the path or paths of the files/folders selected to a program I'm writing in VB.Net to, lets say, display a message box with the paths in it.
3. I need to install the context menu item on multiple machines now and possibly in the future.

So that's really it.  I've looked around and found some good resources such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus but with that I'm having a hard time reading the code and understanding how to implement it in the beginning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help but I ended up using a more basic approach where a registry entry will be installed during the installation process of the program that will pass a program the selected file path(s).